# Memory management issue with CIImage / CGImageRef

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, core-image

Good morning,

I encounter a memory management issue in the video processing software i'm trying to write. (video capture + (almost)real-time processing + display + recording).

The following code is part of the "..didOutputSampleBuffer.." function of AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate.

capturePreviewLayer is a CALayer.
ctx is a CIContext I reuse over and over.
outImage is a vImage_Buffer.

With the commented section kept commented, memory usage is stable and acceptable, but if I uncomment it, memory won't stop increasing. Note that if I leave the filtering operation commented and only keep CIImage creation and conversion back to CGImageRef, the problem remains. (I mean : I don't think this is related to the filter itself).

If I run the XCode's Analyse, it points a potential memory leak if this part is uncommented, but none if it is commented.

Does anybody has an idea to explain and fix this ?
Thank you very much !

Note : I prefer not to use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and its filters property.

```
CGImageRef convertedImage = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer(&outImage, &outputFormat, NULL, NULL, 0, &err);

//CIImage * img = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:convertedImage];
////[acc setValue:img forKey:@"inputImage"];
////img = [acc valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
//convertedImage = [self.ctx createCGImage:img fromRect:img.extent];

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   self.capturePreviewLayer.contents = (__bridge id)(convertedImage);
});

CGImageRelease(convertedImage);
free(outImage.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer()` and `-[CIContext createCGImage:fromRect:]` give you a reference you are responsible for releasing. You are only releasing one of them.

When you replace the value of `convertedImage` with the new `CGImageRef`, you are losing the reference to the previous one without releasing it. You need to add another call to `CGImageRelease(convertedImage)` after your last use of the old image and before you lose that reference.

Comment: Effectively, I can see now the memory increasing and decreasing at regular intervals, globally remaining in an acceptable level. Thanks for your help !